# It is possible to approximate this function by continuously differentiable increasing odd functions?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $p>1$ and let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(t)=|t|^{p-1}$ if $t \geq 0$ and $g(t)=-|t|^{p-1}$ if $t<0$. It is possible to construct an sequence $(g_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ of continuously differentiable odd increasing functions such that $g_m \to g$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

The reason I'm searching such approximation is that if this is possible I will be able to understand a nice regularity result for an Elliptic PDE, any help will be very useful, thank you.

Comment: Under what norm would you like the sequence to converge uniformly? $||\cdot||_\infty$? Because in case the space $C^1(\mathbf{R}, \mathbf{R})$ is complete with respect to that norm, the (uniform) limit of a converging sequence in that space is an element of the space itself. And there are (semi)norms that make $C^1$ complete.

Comment: $$g_m(t) := t(t^2+m^{-2})^{(p-2)/2}$$ should work.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Nice, I think your sequence of functions works just fine :)